# How does Web Service works in Android

Tags: android, database, web-services, server

I'm studying android and I have a question. How to transfer data between app and client ? which DBMS I can use ? and how to make my laptop become server ? all of this I just want to practice. Thanks for all advice !

Comment: Question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a server program which service requests via web services. So this is the server program which has access to DB and choosing DBMS does not depends on android app. when your server program reads data from DB, it'll send them to android app in JSON or XML format (most common formats).
you can setup a local network in your laptop and connect you cell phone to that. but for testing purpose you can use emulator in your laptop.